# Proof of inequality

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities

I have problems with proving inequality :

> $${a^{2}}+b^2+c^2+\frac{2}{5}abc<50$$

where $a,b,c$ are the lengths of triangle's sides, and the circumference of the triangle is $10$.

Thanks.

Comment: what do u mean by a circumference of a triangle.

Comment: Presumably by "circumference" what's meant is what I'd call "perimeter".

Answer (score 14):

Consider the polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$. Multiplied out, this is

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)
&=&
x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+ac+bc)x-abc
\\
&=&
x^3-10x^2+(ab+ac+bc)x-abc\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

We also have

$$10^2=(a+b+c)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2) + 2(ab+ac+bc)\;,$$
$$ab+ac+bc=\frac{100-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}\;,$$

and thus

$$
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)
=
x^3-10x^2+\frac{100-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}x-abc\;.
$$

Now since $a$, $b$ and $c$ form a triangle with perimeter $10$, they must all be less than $5$. Thus the value of the polynomial for $x=5$ is positive, that is,

$$
5^3-10\cdot5^2+\frac{100-(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2}\cdot5-abc>0\;,
$$

which upon rearrangement becomes your inequality.

Comment: Bravo!${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that
$$\frac{(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{10}+\frac{2}{5}abc<\frac{(a+b+c)^3}{20}$$ or
$$(a+b+c)^3>8abc+2(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3+3a^2b+3a^2c+2abc)>8abc+2\sum_{cyc}(a^3+a^2b+a^2c)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(-a^3+a^2b+a^2c-\frac{2}{3}abc\right)>0$$ or
$$(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)>0$$
Done!